# Maintain 9:16 portrait aspect ratio container with three 9:16 landscapes inside

Tags: html, css, layout, sass

I've been trying to produce a CSS to construct the following layout. Any advice?  Thanks.

[Vertical Screen: 3 Frame Horizontal Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn3Cg.png)

Comment: Use  an [aspect ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/aspect-ratio) @media query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the aspect-ration. I didn't know about that.  I was using @media only screen and (min-width:1080px) and (orientation: portrait) but couldn't get the three 16:9 div's to stay together when the screen is other than the 1080p portrait format.